# Server 2012 Datacenter: does Microsoft charge per core or per processor?

Tags: datacenter

For Server 2012 Datacenter do they charge per 2 physical cpu or per 2 cores?

Example if I have an EVGA Classified SR-X motherboard with 2 Intel Xeon E5-2687W, 8 core cpus, will I only need to buy one Windows Server 2012 Datacenter ($4500) or will I have to buy 8 of them ($36,000)?

Comment: Ask your reseller, or check Microsoft's site.

Comment: It's per processor, not per core. But why wouldn't you contact them directly instead of asking here? I've never understood why people post licensing questions here instead of asking the vendor directly.

Comment: Licensing questions are explicitely off-topic here: http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue

Comment: Thanks, and sorry I didn't notice that. I don't really want to spend thousands on MS software, the question was hypothetical for my blog.

Comment: @DrtupwVffe You can call a reseller without making a purchase...

Answer (score 2):

[A quick look at the documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/windowsserver2012.aspx#tab=4) reveals that a single license of Standard or Datacenter covers two physical processors.

Comment: I am kind of surprised that a 50k user answers a question which the FAQ explicitely declares off-topic... 8-)

Comment: Teaching people how to learn, and such.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Just because something is about to be closed doesn't mean you can't throw a guy a bone once in a while if it's an easy answer :) It just so happens I've spent the last week up to my elbows in System Center and Windows Server licensing.